# How do i remove an object from the stage if a does not touch b as3

Tags: flash

I'm trying to create a Plants vs Zombie-like game in flash. When i put "A" on "B" it starts to shoot bullets. We were instructed that the objects should still be allowed to transfer to "C." However, when i try to transfer "A" on "C" a bullet remains on "B." How do I remove the bullet from "B" once I remove "A" from "B" ??

Comment: Can you give us more details ?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code its hard to figure out were your going wrong.

however, here is a working Plants vs Zombies Source that might help you with your endeavours.

create a flash file called 'pvz.fla' set its class to 'Main' then save.
inside pvz.fla's library create 5 MovieClips
bulletMc
plantMC
selectorMC
sunMC
zombieMC

draw appropriate images in each MC.
make sure all MC's have Actionscript Linkage in their properties.
make linkage names the same MC names eg.
bulletMc
plantMC
selectorMC
sunMC
zombieMC

next create an actionscript file called 'Main.as'
inside Main.as put the following code.

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextField;
public class Main extends Sprite {
    //
    // arrays to store game field information
    //
    private var plantsArray:Array;// plants placed in the game field
    private var zombiesArray:Array;//zombies placed in the game field
    // 
    // timers
    //
    private var flowersTimer:Timer=new Timer(10000);// timer to make flowers fall down
    private var zombieTimer:Timer=new Timer(4000);// timer to make zombies come in
    //
    // containers
    //
    private var sunContainer:Sprite=new Sprite();// container for all suns
    private var plantContainer:Sprite=new Sprite();// container for all plants
    public var bulletContainer:Sprite=new Sprite();// container for all bullets
    private var zombieContainer:Sprite=new Sprite();// container for all zombies
    private var overlayContainer:Sprite=new Sprite();// container of all overlays
    //
    // actors
    //
    private var movingPlant:plantMc;// plant the player can drag on game field
    private var selector:selectorMc;// the selector square to show the playere where he's going to place the plant
    //
    // other variables
    //
    private var money:uint=0;// amout of money owned by the player
    private var moneyText:TextField=new TextField  ;// dynamic text field where to show player's money
    private var playerMoving:Boolean=false;// Boolean variable to tell us if the player is moving a plant (true) or not (false)
    private var totalZombies:uint=0;//total amount of zombies placed in game
    public function Main():void {
        setupField();// initializes the game
        drawField();// draws the game field
        fallingSuns();// initializes the falling suns
        addPlants();// initialized the plants
        addZombies();// initializes the zombies
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrm);
    }
    //
    // game field setup. arrays to store plants and zombies information are created
    //
    private function setupField():void {
        plantsArray=new Array();
        zombiesArray=new Array();
        for (var i:uint=0; i<5; i++) {
            plantsArray[i]=new Array();
            zombiesArray[i]=new Array();
            for (var j:uint=0; j<9; j++) {
                plantsArray[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
    }
    //
    // showing the amount of money
    //
    private function updateMoney():void {
        moneyText.text="Money: "+money.toString();
    }
    //
    // game field drawing and children hierarchy management
    //
    private function drawField():void {
        var fieldSprite:Sprite=new Sprite();
        var randomGreen:Number;
        addChild(fieldSprite);
        fieldSprite.graphics.lineStyle(1,0xFFFFFF);
        for (var i:uint=0; i<5; i++) {
            for (var j:uint=0; j<9; j++) {
                randomGreen=(125+Math.floor(Math.random()*50))*256;
                fieldSprite.graphics.beginFill(randomGreen);
                fieldSprite.graphics.drawRect(25+65*j,80+75*i,65,75);
            }
        }
        addChild(sunContainer);
        addChild(plantContainer);
        addChild(bulletContainer);
        addChild(zombieContainer);
        addChild(overlayContainer);
        overlayContainer.addChild(moneyText);
        updateMoney();
        moneyText.textColor=0xFFFFFF;
        moneyText.height=40;
    }
    //
    // zombies initialization
    //
    private function addZombies():void {
        zombieTimer.start();
        zombieTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,newZombie);
    }
    //
    // adding a new zombie
    //
    private function newZombie(e:TimerEvent):void {
        var zombie:zombieMc=new zombieMc();// constructs the zombie
        totalZombies++;
        zombieContainer.addChild(zombie);// adds the zombie
        zombie.zombieRow=Math.floor(Math.random()*5);// chooses a random row where to place the zombie
        zombie.name="zombie_"+totalZombies;//gives a name to the zombie
        zombiesArray[zombie.zombieRow].push(zombie.name);// adds the zombie in the row-th row
        zombie.x=660;// places the zombie on the board, outside the stage to the right
        zombie.y=zombie.zombieRow*75+115;
    }
    //
    // suns initialization
    //
    private function fallingSuns():void {
        flowersTimer.start();
        flowersTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, newSun);
    }
    //
    // adding a new sun
    //
    private function newSun(e:TimerEvent):void {
        var sunRow:uint=Math.floor(Math.random()*5);// random row
        var sunCol:uint=Math.floor(Math.random()*9);// random column
        var sun:sunMc = new sunMc();// constructs the sun
        sun.buttonMode=true;// makes the mouse change shape when over the plant
        sunContainer.addChild(sun);// adds the sun
        sun.x=52+sunCol*65;// places the sun in the proper column
        sun.destinationY=130+sunRow*75;// definines the sun y destination point
        sun.y=-20;// places the sun out to the upper side of the stage
        sun.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,sunClicked);// listener to be triggered when the sun is clicked
    }
    //
    // handling clicks on suns
    //
    private function sunClicked(e:MouseEvent):void {
        e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,sunClicked);// removes the CLICK listener
        money+=5;// makes the player earn money (5)
        updateMoney();// updates money text
        var sunToRemove:sunMc=e.currentTarget as sunMc;// defines which sun we need to remove
        sunContainer.removeChild(sunToRemove);// removes the sun
    }
    //
    // building the plant toolbar (only 1 plant at the moment)
    //
    private function addPlants():void {
        var plant:plantMc=new plantMc();// constructs a new plant
        overlayContainer.addChild(plant);// adds the plant
        plant.buttonMode=true;// makes the mouse change shape when over the plant
        plant.x=90;
        plant.y=40;
        plant.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onPlantClicked);// listener to be triggered once the plant is clicked
    }
    //
    // handling clicks on plants
    //
    private function onPlantClicked(e:MouseEvent):void {
        // let's see if the player has enough money (10) to afford the plant and isn't currently dragging a plant
        if (money>=10&&! playerMoving) {
            money-=10;// pays the plant
            updateMoney();// updates money text
            selector=new selectorMc();// constructs a new selector
            selector.visible=false;// makes the selector invisible
            overlayContainer.addChild(selector);// adds the selector
            movingPlant=new plantMc();// constructs a new moving plant
            movingPlant.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,placePlant);// lister to be triggered once the moving plant is clicked
            overlayContainer.addChild(movingPlant);// adds the moving plant
            playerMoving=true;// tells the script the player is actually moving a plant
        }
    }
    //
    // placing the plant on the game field
    //
    private function placePlant(e:MouseEvent):void {
        var plantRow:int=Math.floor((mouseY-80)/75);
        var plantCol:int=Math.floor((mouseX-25)/65);
        // let's see if the tile is inside the game field and it's free
        if (plantRow>=0&&plantCol>=0&&plantRow<5&&plantCol<9&&plantsArray[plantRow][plantCol]==0) {
            var placedPlant:plantMc=new plantMc();// constructs the plant to be placed
            placedPlant.name="plant_"+plantRow+"_"+plantCol;// gives the plant a name
            placedPlant.fireRate=75;// plant fire rate, in frames
            placedPlant.recharge=0;// plant recharge. When recharge is equal to fireRate, the plant is ready to fire
            placedPlant.isFiring=false;// Boolean value to tell if the plant is firing
            placedPlant.plantRow=plantRow;// plant row
            plantContainer.addChild(placedPlant);// adds the plant
            placedPlant.x=plantCol*65+57;
            placedPlant.y=plantRow*75+115;
            playerMoving=false;// tells the script the player is no longer moving
            movingPlant.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,placePlant);// removes the CLICK listener from the draggable plant
            overlayContainer.removeChild(selector);// removes the selector
            overlayContainer.removeChild(movingPlant);// removes the plant itself
            plantsArray[plantRow][plantCol]=1;// updates game array adding the new plant
        }
    }
    //
    // core function to be executed at every frame. The whole game is managed here
    //
    private function onEnterFrm(e:Event):void {
        var i:int;
        var j:int;
        //
        // plants management
        //
        for (i=0; i<plantContainer.numChildren; i++) {
            var currentPlant:plantMc=plantContainer.getChildAt(i) as plantMc;
            // let's see if the plant can fire
            if (currentPlant.recharge==currentPlant.fireRate&&! currentPlant.isFiring) {
                // let's see if there are zombies in the same row of the plant
                if (zombiesArray[currentPlant.plantRow].length>0) {
                    // let's scan through all zombies
                    for (j=0; j<zombiesArray[currentPlant.plantRow].length>0; j++) {
                        var targetZombie:zombieMc=zombieContainer.getChildByName(zombiesArray[currentPlant.plantRow][j]) as zombieMc;// gets the j-th zombie
                        // if the zombie is on the right of the plant
                        if (targetZombie.x>currentPlant.x) {
                            var bullet:bulletMc=new bulletMc();// constructs a new bullet
                            bulletContainer.addChild(bullet);// adds the bullet
                            bullet.x=currentPlant.x;
                            bullet.y=currentPlant.y;
                            bullet.sonOf=currentPlant;// sets the bullet as a son of the current plant
                            currentPlant.recharge=0;// the plant must recharge 
                            currentPlant.isFiring=true;// the plant is firing
                            break;// exits the j for loop
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // let's see if the plant has to recharge
            if (currentPlant.recharge<currentPlant.fireRate) {
                currentPlant.recharge++;// recharges the plant
            }
        }
        //
        // bullets management
        //
        for (i=0; i<bulletContainer.numChildren; i++) {
            var movingBullet:bulletMc=bulletContainer.getChildAt(i) as bulletMc;
            movingBullet.x+=3;//moves each bullet right by 3 pixels
            var firingPlant:plantMc=movingBullet.sonOf as plantMc;// finds the plant which shot the bullet
            // let's see if the bullet flew out of the screen
            if (movingBullet.x>650) {
                firingPlant.isFiring=false;// the plant is not longer firing
                bulletContainer.removeChild(movingBullet);// removes the bullet
            } else {
                for (j=0; j<zombieContainer.numChildren; j++) {
                    var movingZombie:zombieMc=zombieContainer.getChildAt(j) as zombieMc;
                    // let's see if a zombie has been hit by a bullet
                    if (movingZombie.hitTestPoint(movingBullet.x,movingBullet.y,true)) {
                        movingZombie.alpha-=0.3;// decreases zombie energy (alpha)
                        firingPlant.isFiring=false;// the plant is not longer firing
                        bulletContainer.removeChild(movingBullet);// removes the bullet
                        // let's see if zombie's energy (alpha) reached zero
                        if (movingZombie.alpha<0) {
                            zombiesArray[movingZombie.zombieRow].splice(zombiesArray[movingZombie.zombieRow].indexOf(movingZombie.name),1);// remove the zombie from the row 
                            zombieContainer.removeChild(movingZombie);// removes the zombie
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //
        // zombies management
        //
        var zombieColumn:int;
        for (i=0; i<zombieContainer.numChildren; i++) {
            movingZombie=zombieContainer.getChildAt(i) as zombieMc;
            zombieColumn = Math.floor((movingZombie.x-25)/65);// gets zombie column
            // let's see if there is a plant in the same tile
            if (zombieColumn<0||zombieColumn>8||plantsArray[movingZombie.zombieRow][zombieColumn]==0) {
                movingZombie.x-=0.5;// moves each zombie left by 1/2 pixels
            } else {
                // the zombie attacks!!
                var attackedPlant:plantMc=plantContainer.getChildByName("plant_"+movingZombie.zombieRow+"_"+zombieColumn) as plantMc;
                attackedPlant.alpha-=0.01;// drains plant energy
                // let's see if the plant died
                if (attackedPlant.alpha<0) {
                    plantsArray[movingZombie.zombieRow][zombieColumn]=0;//removes the plant from the array
                    plantContainer.removeChild(attackedPlant);//removes the plant Display Object from Display List
                }
            }
        }
        //
        // suns management
        //
        for (i=0; i<sunContainer.numChildren; i++) {
            var fallingSun:sunMc=sunContainer.getChildAt(i) as sunMc;
            // let's see if the sun is still falling because it did not reach its destination
            if (fallingSun.y<fallingSun.destinationY) {
                fallingSun.y++;// moves the sun down by one pixel
            } else {
                fallingSun.alpha-=0.01;// makes the sun fade away
                // let's see if the sun disappeared
                if (fallingSun.alpha<0) {
                    fallingSun.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,sunClicked);// removes the CLICK listener from the sun
                    sunContainer.removeChild(fallingSun);// removes the sun
                }
            }
        }
        //
        // placing plant process
        //
        if (playerMoving) {
            movingPlant.x=mouseX;
            movingPlant.y=mouseY;
            var plantRow:int=Math.floor((mouseY-80)/75);
            var plantCol:int=Math.floor((mouseX-25)/65);
            // let's see if the plant is inside the game field
            if (plantRow>=0&&plantCol>=0&&plantRow<5&&plantCol<9) {
                selector.visible=true;// shows the selector
                selector.x=25+plantCol*65;
                selector.y=80+plantRow*75;
            } else {
                selector.visible=false;// hide the selector
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Save and Run.

I got this source a year or so ago from an opensource site, I would love to Ref the original contributor and site but contributor didn't comment any link or name in code. 
just code as is.

Anyway hope this helps you somewhat.